# getting random int from function to new function

Tags: java, function, recursion, random

I'm trying to do a simple guessing game in java. I've got functions for creating a random number and guessing the number. However, in guessing the number there is no variable declared as a random to guess. I'm wondering how to get my random number from one function to be available in the guessing function. Here is my code:

```
public static void Final(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
}

public static void Guess(){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pick = scan.nextInt();

    if(pick > number){
        System.out.println("Your number is too high.");
        Guess();            
    }else if(pick < number){
        System.out.println("Your number is too low.");
        Guess();
    }else if(pick == number){
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }
```

Comment: Change your function to take a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your `getFinal()` method to return an int:

```
public static int getFinal(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
}
```

then in your `makeGuess()` method:

```
public static void makeGuess(){
    int number = getFinal(); //number to be guessed

    myLoop:
         while(true){ //loop until they get it right
              Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
              int pick = scan.nextInt();
              if(pick > number){
                  System.out.println("Your number is too high.");            
              }else if(pick < number){
                  System.out.println("Your number is too low.");
              }else if(pick == number){
                  System.out.println("Correct!");
                  break myLoop;
              }
         }
}
```

also, as a side note, methods should be camelCase, and contain a verb in their name.

Comment: Thank you for the side note. It compiles properly now, but every wrong guess generates a new random. Is there a way to store the random and just continue guessing the current random number? Sorry if that's confusing.

Comment: put everything but the int number = final(); part into a while loop

Comment: something like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099928/how-to-exit-java-loop-while-loop-in-a-basic-guessing-game

Comment: @Christopher if you want to store the random then you need to be a bit clever. Check my answer.

Comment: fixed now to fully address the question, this now gives a more efficient solution